# How to let Parent component get click events of child components?

Tags: delphi, components, parent-child, firemonkey

I have a FireMonkey application with multiple buttons on it (actually, rectangles). I want to have one procedure called on any click on the Form, besides the specific action of each button.

Since the `HitTest` of each child component is set to True, the parent's `HitTest` is automatically false.

So what is the right way to deal with this?

A silly workaround would be to assign this procedure to each button's `OnClick` event, but this will not make any sense when I have a Form with hundreds of buttons on it.

Comment: In VCL, this would be very easy using the `TApplication.OnMessage` event. But that doesn't exist in FMX. So, unless you use a platform-specific message/mouse hook on the Form's underlying window, I don't know how else to address this in FMX.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. When you say that you don't want to assign OnClick event to each button how do you intend to fire needed code when clicking on these buttons? Also why do you need hundreds of buttons?

Comment: @SilverWarior, I already implemented `OnClick` for each button and it would be nonsense to copy and paste the same procedure to all these `onClick` events, rather have one piece of code that fires on each and every click besides firing the individual `onClick` event

Comment: I don't think there is much easier way than simply manually calling your forms OnClick event method from every button event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I actually compile only for Windows, so will I be able to use the `TApplication.OnMessage`?

Comment: @codeGood "*I already implemented OnClick for each button and it would be nonsense to copy and paste the same procedure to all these onClick events*" - you don't need multiple procedures. You can assign a single procedure to multiple events, and then use its `Sender` parameter to differentiate which button is being clicked each time.

Comment: @codeGood "*I actually compile only for Windows*" - then why are you using FMX and not VCL? "*will I be able to use TApplication.OnMessage?*" - not in FMX, no. But in VCL, yes. Mouse events are based on [queued messages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages) and VCL's `TApplication.OnMessage` event is called for every queued message before it is dispatched to its target window. You can process `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` messages as needed. Not impossible in FMX, but you would have to hook the message queue with `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Comment: The proper way to do what you want is to write a single `OnClick` event handler and assign that single handler to each of your rectangles, and then use the `Sender` parameter when the event is called to distinguish which rectangle was clicked. You don't need to jump through any kinds of hoops or do what your question title asks at all. The same method works on both VCL and FMX as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for vcl.
you can find component base of mouse position by this code:

```
var
  ctrl : TWinControl;
begin

 ctrl := FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos);
 if ctrl.Name = '' then
   ShowMessage(ctrl.Owner.Name);
```

For FireMonkey no result founded but You can get mouse position on form and analyze component base on result of that point and find name of it then proceed to your event base of that component.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Interceptor/Interposer Class of TRectangle did the job!
Thanks to everyone for their input.